# How to visualize a Pandas Dataframe in R chunk Quarto?

Tags: python, r, pandas, quarto

I was wondering if there is an option to use a `Pandas` dataframe created in a Python chunk, in your R chunk to visualize the dataframe. Here is some reproducible code:

````
---
title: "How to use Pandas Dataframe in R chunk"
format: html
engine: knitr
---

Example code:

```{python}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,3]], columns = ['v1', 'v2'])
print(df)
```

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = v1, y = v2)) + geom_point()
```
````

This produces the following error:

```
Error in `ggplot()`:
!   You're passing a function as global data.
  Have you misspelled the `data` argument in `ggplot()`
Backtrace:
 1. ggplot2::ggplot(data = df, aes(x = v1, y = v2))
 2. ggplot2:::ggplot.function(data = df, aes(x = v1, y = v2))
```

This happens of course because it can't find the dataframe `df` created in the python chunk. I also loaded the `reticulate` package and tried using `py$df` in R chunk without success. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to use a `Pandas` dataframe in your R chunk to visualize it in `Quarto`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`{reticulate}` docs](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/r_markdown.html#calling-python-from-r),

> All objects created within Python chunks are available to R using the py object exported by the reticulate package.

which means that you have to either use `library(reticulate)` in the `qmd` file or at least use `reticulate::py`

````
---
title: "How to use Pandas Dataframe in R chunk"
format: html
engine: knitr
---

Example code:

```{python}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,3]], columns = ['v1', 'v2'])
print(df)
```

```{r}
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = reticulate::py$df, aes(x = v1, y = v2)) + geom_point()
```


```{r}
library(reticulate)

ggplot(data = py$df, aes(x = v1, y = v2)) + geom_point()
```
````

---

[image: ggplot with pandas in quarto]

---